# Reshape the Columns of Data Frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame (for example)

```
 Week Bags
 4     5
 6     3
10     5
13     7
18     5
23     1
30     9
31     9
32     4
33     7
35     1
38     2
42     2
47     2
```

'Week' column denotes the week number in an year and 'Bags' denotes the number of bags used by a small firm. 
I want my data frame in the form of
`Week Bags
 1    0
 2    0
 3    0
 4    5
 5    0
 6    3
 7    0
 8    0
 9    0
10    5`
and so on, in order to plot the weekly changes in number of bags.
I am sure it is very silly question but I could not find any way. Please help in this direction.

Comment: `aggregate(Bags ~ Week, data = rbind(dd, data.frame(Week = 1:50, Bags = 0)), sum)` will also work for this example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create another dataset

```
df2 <- data.frame(Week= 1:max(df1$Week))
```

and then `merge` with the first dataset

```
res<- merge(df1, df2, all=TRUE)
res$Bags[is.na(res$Bags)] <- 0
head(res,10)
#  Week Bags
#1     1    0
#2     2    0
#3     3    0
#4     4    5
#5     5    0
#6     6    3
#7     7    0
#8     8    0
#9     9    0
#10   10    5
```

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
res1 <- setDT(df1, key='Week')[J(Week = 1:max(Week))][is.na(Bags), Bags:=0][]
```

Comment: Dear Akrun, Thanks for quick reply. My data frame is derived from some previous calculations. It is showing "Week" as factor. This is creating trouble in the solution provided by you.

Comment: @Pankaj You can convert to `numeric` by `df1$Week <- as.numeric(as.character(df1$Week))`

Comment: Got it, I did but not but outside. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: That data.table solution is money. +1